# How to find out if path meets certain parent?

Tags: c++, search, boost, boost-filesystem

So we have a parent like `somepath/**` so if any one sends to us `somepath/myfolder/file` we would receive `true` and if we would receive `someotherpath/` we would get `false`. So how to find out if a path meets certain parent?

Comment: What's a "parten"? Do you mean "parent"?

Comment: I believe "parten" is a word in German, and Google says it's used in Spanish as well, but not English -- could you clarify what you mean by it? Without knowing what you mean by it, your question is difficult to decipher (at best).

Comment: @Jerry: As a native German, I can tell that its not ;) A quick google on "parten path" suggests "parent path", that tricked me into thinking he could mean "parent". Could make some sense...

Comment: @kiw: I'll take your word for it -- when it comes to German, I'm going from distant memories at best. Parent does *sort of* make sense, but even if it's the case, he still hasn't included enough to answer. For example, does he want to deal with things like symbolic links, or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to normalize both paths, then you do a [simple substring comparison](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/) to see if your path in question starts with the normalized reference path.

Normalizing includes adding the current working directory to a relative path, case normalization if your file system is case-insensitive, probably resolving symbolic links and maybe even testing for hard links. If you want to allow the file itself to be a symbolic link you have to extract the path portion prior to normalization.

I've done this in linux using the `realpath()` function and it works very well, even if the reference path contains symlinks. Don't know how to do it with boost, though.

Comment: and since the question includes the boost_filesystem tag, I suggest using the `system_complete()` method for normalization